# Find Bps given a star graph

Tags: digital-logic, serial, telecommunications, encoding

Today I wrote finals for the semester in the subject "Introduction to Telecommunications".1 question was like this:

Suppose we have a star graph with 64 dots in it.That would mean we are dealing with PSK encoding with 64 different phases which encode [image]  bits.Is that correct?For the transmission speed of bits [image]

Comment: QPSK is more likely than PSK. \$2^6 = 64\$. But, if it's a star diagram then PSK.

Comment: Yeah with 64 we get 64 different phases right?There isnt a possibility for some other number of phases correct?

Comment: Based on what details you have provided there will be 64 phase angles.